# C++ cast specific pairs of enums

Tags: c++

I need a function which casts the type From to type To (To and From are enums), however an enum E1 can be casted only to E2, I need to get an error if the user tries to cast E1 to E3 for example.

```
template<typename From, typename To>
static To map(From f){
    return static_cast<To>(f);
}
```

How can I do this?
Thank you!

Comment: Go with template specialization

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution: static_assert

```
template<typename From, typename To>
static To map(From f) {
    static_assert(!(std::is_same<From, E1>::value && std::is_same<To, E3>::value),
                  "cannot cast from E1 to E3");

    return static_cast<To>(f);
}

auto main() -> int {
    E1 a;
    const auto b = map<E1, E2>(a); // compiles
    const auto c = map<E1, E3>(a); // won't compile

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's interesting your solution, however static_assert evaluates at compile time and From and To at runtime

Comment: What's up with the `->`? Is that now a part of C++? Oh I see, main is a lambda function? Cool!

Comment: Ionut Yes, correct. How does your code calling the function look like?
@Smac89 yes, you can declare main(...) now like this :)

Answer (score 1):

With template specialization, you can specify how to work for different types. Have a look in the below example.

```
template<typename To, typename From>
To map(From f){
    return static_cast<To>(f);
}

template<>
E2 map(E1 f){
    return static_cast<E2>(f);
}
```

When `map()` function is called with type `E1` then the specialized template function is executed instead of the normal template function. But other than type `E1` normal template function is called.

This will force the user to cast `E1` to `E2` only. If you want to throw exception or `assert` modify the definition as your wish.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use template specialization. Also, you'll want to move the `To` template parameter to be the first template argument as it will be the return type and the compiler won't be able to infer it.

First, create the primary template function, but don't provide an implementation of it:

```
template<typename To, typename From>
To map(From from);
```

Now, do specialization for the mappings that make sense:

```
template<>
E2 map(E1 from)
{
    return static_cast<E2>(from);
}
```

As you've provided the specialization for the mappings that make sense you'll get an error if you try to call ones that don't. For example, on VS2012 if you do:

```
E3 value = map<E3>(e1_value);
```

You'll get an "unresovled external symbol" error as there's no implementation for the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution using Concepts. Concepts are implemented to my knowledge only in gcc6 which is still experimental.

```
#include <type_traits>

enum E1{};
enum E2{};
enum E3{};

template <class T, class U> concept bool Same = std::is_same<T,U>::value;

template<typename From, typename To>
static To map(From f)
 requires !(Same<From, E1> && Same<To, E3>)
{
    return static_cast<To>(f);
}

int main()
{
    E1 e1;
    E2 e2;
    E3 e3;

    map<E1, E2>(e1); // Ok
    map<E1, E3>(e1); // Compile Error !
}
```

will show error as below:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:23:19: error: cannot call function 'To map(From) requires predicate(!((Same<From, E1>) && (Same<To, E3>))) [with From = E1; To = E3]'
     map<E1, E3>(e1);
                   ^
prog.cc:10:11: note:   constraints not satisfied
 static To map(From f)
           ^~~
```

http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/mEG3Rl5jaMXj0GVg

compiled with experimental version of gcc 6.0:

$ g++ prog.cc -Wall -Wextra -I/usr/local/boost-1.60.0/include -std=gnu++1z "-fconcepts"